# Well-definedness of group law on elliptic curves?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, cryptography

I am working through the section on elliptic curves in *An Introduction to Mathematical Cryptography* by Hoffstein, Pipher, and Silverman.

My understanding of the group law ("addition") for points on elliptic curves is as follows:

> Given two points $p$ and $q$ on an elliptic curve $E=\{(x,y):y^2=ax^3+bx+c\}\cup\{\mathcal O\}$, define a binary operation $+$ as
>
> - If $p$ and $q$ are distinct but lie on the same vertical line, or if $p=q$ and the line tangent to $E$ at $p$ is vertical, then $p+q=\mathcal O$.
> - If $p=q$ then draw a line tangent to $E$ at $p$. This line crosses another point $r\in E$. Then $p+q=-r$, where $-r$ denotes $r$ reflected across the $x$-axis.
> - If $p$ and $q$ are distinct but do not lie on the same vertical line, then there is a (distinct) third point $r\in E$ on the line connecting $p$ and $q$. Then $p+q=-r$, wherer $-r$ denotes $r$ reflected across the $x$-axis.

My question is: How do we know $r$ exists? In other words, why does every non-vertical line that crosses two points on $E$ also cross a third point on $E$?

Answer (score 1):

From Bezout's theorem, E(degree $3$) and line (degree $1$) intersect at exactly $3$ points. As we know the line and $E$ intersect at $p,q$. Thus,the line should crosses at yet another one point, $r$.

Also, vertical line also intersects with $E$ at exactly three points( first two points, and infinite point $O$).

Comment: You probably mean "degree $3$" and "degree $1$" instead of saying "$3$-dimensional"  and "$1$-dimensional", since everything in sight is a curve.

Comment: Thank you, I edited.

Comment: It’s also worth noting that if the coordinates of the points $P$ and $Q$ are all in the field $k$, then the coordinates of the  sum-point $P+Q$ will also lie in $k$.